# Code hangs when receiveing data on UART using Gpio 15(RX)

Tags: serial, uart, serial-console

I enabled the UART interface inside the /boot/config.txt file. I know I have correctly selected the serial port because `ser.write(data_to_send.encode())` gets executed successfully.
The line where my code gets stuck is `received_data = ser.read(2).decode()`.

I have connected GPIO14(UART TX) with GPIO15(UART RX) using a physical wire. To receive the same data being sent.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

I am also attaching my code as a reference. Thanks

```
import serial

serial_port = '/dev/ttyS0' baud_rate = 9600

 def send_data(serial_port, baud_rate, data_to_send):

    # Open the serial connection
    
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)

    try:
        # Send data serially
        ser.write(data_to_send.encode())  # Convert string to bytes before sending
        print("Sent: {}".format(data_to_send))

        # You may want to add a delay to allow time for data to be transmitted
        time.sleep(1)

    finally:
        # Close the serial connection
        ser.close()

def receive_data(serial_port, baud_rate):
    # Open the serial connection

    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate)

    try:
        # Read data serially
        received_data = ser.read(2).decode()
        print("Received: {}".format(received_data))

    finally:
        # Close the serial connection
        ser.close()



data_to_send = "Hello, Raspberry Pi!"

send_data(serial_port, baud_rate, data_to_send)

receive_data(serial_port, baud_rate)
```

Comment: I have updated it. Please check. Also, I have used dev/serial0 it's showing the same error. 
Also, can you give examples of "sensible" code?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is behaving as expected.

You close ser in send_data which will discard any data in the buffer.
You open in receive_data, and except in the unlikely circumstance that something will be received before you read the buffer is empty.

Open the port ONCE!

If I wanted to do something simple like this I would use a few lines of code e.g. (untested)

```
with serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate, timeout=1) as ser:
    ser.write(data_to_send.encode())
    print("Received: ", ser.read(2).decode())
```